# How to see dynamic shared library specifications?

Tags: linux, shell, shared-libraries

Which linux command shows library specs architecture and os-bits for which it is built?

Backtground:
While loading shared library I am getting error "cannot open shared object: no such file or directory". With LD_DEBUG="binds" I  found that loader is searching the correct lib path.  I read [here](http://support.ioncube.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/42/4/i-see-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-but-i-know-that-the-loader-exists-why)
that it could be that library is built for other architecture(32 bit) and I am running 64 bit.
so Which linux command shows library specs architecture and os-bits for which it is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` command will give you some generic info about any file. For libraries and programs, it will print the architecture it was built for.

`objdump` can be used for more detailed information.

Comment: thanks. Both of this are useful. Now I see lib is built for my platform, so where do you think I should look?

Comment: Try `ldd` on your executable. That should print the paths `ld` will use to load the libraries. Note that many of those files are in fact links to the real library. Make sure the link isn't stale.